# My nephew is growing a plant for his pre-k class and idk what it is

Tags: identification

[image]

It’s growing very fast, every couple days that I check on it I see it has grown a few inches.

Comment: Does it have a bulbs? How it looked the seed? Do the leaves smell garlic? Wait for the flowers (one or two weeks). Do no eat the leaves (until you have certain identification),